# What makes some pdf files much smaller than others?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a number of PDF textbooks, and some of them are upwards of 400 megabytes for 1000 pages while others (which look similar in quality) are only 10 megabytes for 1500 pages!! I thought it might be the image quality, but the images are fairly similar in quality. Next, I took a look at the text when I zoomed in, and saw that the larger books look like they have rasterized text while the smaller files looked like they had vector text. Is this it?

If so, how can I start making PDF files in vector format? Is it possible to scan a document / use OCR to recognize the text, and then somehow convert the rasterized text into vector format? Also, can you convert rasterized texts into vector format?

Cheers,
 Evans

Comment: Likely one has more images, as images take up a ton of memory compared to plain text.  Maybe the text is rasterized like you said.  There are ways to create vector images, though the technology isn't perfect yet (it depends a lot on the quality of the scan).

Answer (score 0):

Check this command on a sample each from your two different PDF types:

```
 pdfimages -list -f 1 -l 10 the.pdf
```

(Your version of PDF images should be a recent one, the Poppler variant.) This gives you a list of all images from the first 10 pages. It also lists the image dimensions (width, height) in pixels, as well as the image size (in Bytes) and the respective compression.) If you can bear with it, you can also run:

```
 pdfimages -list the.pdf
```

This gives you a list of *all* images from *all* pages.

I bet the larger one has more images listed.

### PDFs from scans vs. PDFs "born digital" ?

Also run:

```
 pdffonts -f 1 -l 10 the.pdf
```

and

```
 pdffonts the.pdf
```

My guess is this: your *large* PDF types do not list any fonts. That means, very likely the pages of these PDFs originate from scanned papers.

The smaller ones were *"born digital"*...